# Title name is not reflected on android

Tags: android, kotlin

My title is not displaying in the app.
I think there is a problem with the intent.
So, my main file is the login page and the code is:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() 
{

lateinit var username: EditText
lateinit var password1: EditText
lateinit var logIn: Button
lateinit var signup: TextView
lateinit var forgotpassword: TextView

val user="DiyaK"
val pass=arrayOf("Diya@2826","Sidd@2826","Prat@2826","Prash@2826")
var titlename: String? = "DiyaK"


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll)
    println("Create called")
    title = "Login Page"
    username=findViewById(R.id.username)
    password1=findViewById(R.id.password1)
    logIn=findViewById(R.id.logIn)
    signup=findViewById(R.id.signup)
    forgotpassword=findViewById(R.id.forgotpassword)

    logIn.setOnClickListener {
        val user1= username.text.toString()
        val pass1=password1.text.toString()
        var name="Diya K"
        if(user1==user) {
            if (pass1 == pass[0]) {
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NewActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                name="Diya K"
                intent.putExtra("Name",name)
            } else if (pass1 == pass[1]) {
                val intent2 = Intent(this@MainActivity, NewActivity6::class.java)
                startActivity(intent2)
                name="Siddhant K"
                intent2.putExtra("Name",name)

            } else if (pass1 == pass[2]) {
                val intent3 = Intent(this@MainActivity, NewActivity3::class.java)
                startActivity(intent3)
                name="Pratibha K"
                intent3.putExtra("Name",name)

            } else if (pass1 == pass[3]) {
                val intent4 = Intent(this@MainActivity, NewActivity4::class.java)
                startActivity(intent4)
                name="Prashant K"
                intent4.putExtra("Name",name)

            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Incorrect! Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }


}
```

}

And, I have created 4 new activities, like for each different page and the code for all are similar, so I am showing the code for one only.

```
class NewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var img: ImageView
lateinit var state: TextView
lateinit var btn: Button
lateinit var btn1: Button
lateinit var header: TextView
lateinit var subheader: TextView
lateinit var hobby: TextView
var title1: String? = "Diya K"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new1)
    img = findViewById(R.id.img)
    state = findViewById(R.id.state)
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn)
    btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1)
    header = findViewById(R.id.header)
    subheader = findViewById(R.id.subheader)
    hobby=findViewById(R.id.hobby)

    btn1.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@NewActivity, "Hurray", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val intent1 = Intent(this@NewActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent1)
    }
    if(intent != null) {
        title1=intent.getStringExtra("Name")
    }
    title=title1

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My title is not displaying in the app. I think there is a problem with the intent.

The problem is you are setting the title after starting the activity

```
startActivity(intent)
name="Diya K"
intent.putExtra("Name",name)
```

Solution is set the extras first before starting the activity. Just swap the lines like below:

```
name="Diya K"
intent.putExtra("Name",name)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(intent != null) {
    title1=intent.getStringExtra("Name")
}
title=title1

header.setText(title)// you get value but not set
```